# is there a way to programaticly open/show the applicationDockMenu

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

is there a way to programaticly open/show the applicationDockMenu

this is the menu you get when you right click on an open app in the dock

Comment: Imagine what a world would be like where the dock menu just opened spontaneously. Would you really want your computer to act like that?

Comment: that'd be great, feels "freeing" anyway to have the menu not closing after i clicked on an item?

Comment: I seriously doubt there's any way to accomplish this. The dock menu is managed by the system's Dock application, which you have no control over.